# retrieving date Type from database and pass it to a java.sql.Date object

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql

well I am new with hibernate and here is my problem:

I'm trying to get a table's information from my database using query below

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Select new final.project.profileReport (u.firstname, u.lastname, u.Mail, u.gender, u.bithday)"
            + "from profile u");
```

and my profileReport class is :

```
public class profileReport 
{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String mail;
    private String gender;
    private Date birthday;

    public profileReport(String firstname, String lastname, String mail, String gender, Date birthday)
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
}
```

and i am getting a "could not resolve property" error

my birthday field type in database is "date"

i tried to change my birthday type several times but nothing...!!!

somebody help me please

Comment: use `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: Is it a misstake that you wrote `(u.firstname, u.lastname, u.Mail, u.gender, u.bithday)` rather than `(u.firstname, u.lastname, u.Mail, u.gender, u.birthday)` ?

Comment: well that is not the problem...it just happend... changing the code several times

Comment: try to use the same property names. like change Mail to mail (case) and bithday to birthday(spelling mistake) !